# Not able to update value of entered column of table using python?

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

```
 import pymysql
 import os

 conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',database='pyp',user='root',password='')

 a = conn.cursor()

 i= raw_input('enter column name : ')

 sql='UPDATE report SET %s = "xyz" WHERE Id = 1'

 a.execute(sql,(i))

 conn.commit()

 conn.close()
```

Comment: Improved Formatting
Cannot update value of entered column of table using python

```
 import pymysql

 import os

 conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',database='pyp',user='root',password='')

 a = conn.cursor()

 i= raw_input('enter column name : ')

 sql='UPDATE report SET %s = "xyz" WHERE Id = 1'

 a.execute(sql,(i))

 conn.commit()

 conn.close()
```

.

.

[expected output]--------------------------->

is to update the value selected column whose id is 1 to xyx.

program should ask the column name and change value of entered column name.

[error]--------->

enter column name : name

ProgrammingError: (1064, u'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'name\' = "name" WHERE Id = 1\' at line 1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be trying to pass 'name' key as 'name' key 
do like this -

```
sql='UPDATE report SET {} = "xyz" WHERE Id = 1'
a.execute(sql.format(str(i)))
```

Let me know, if it solves your problem.

Comment: it worked.
what to do for the query 
***i= raw_input('enter column name')
***h= raw_input('enter id')
****sql='UPDATE report SET {} = "xyz" WHERE Id = s%'
how to execute??

Comment: you can add like this - "UPDATE report SET {0} = "xyz" WHERE Id = {1}".format(i, h)